# Update on h:selectBooleanCheckbox loose css

Tags: css, jsf, selectbooleancheckbox

I have a problem regarding rendering h:selectBooleanCheckbox after ajax event on selectOneMenu is triggered.

When I open the page the select items displays values (Tip) and checkbox near select item is rendered OK (picture bellow).
[image]

Then when I change value in select item the checkbox style changes (picture below).
[image]

I am using also Primefaces version 5.2

HTML code:

```html
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{someController.purpose}" id="purpose">
  <f:selectItems value="#{someController.typeOptions.values()}" var="option" itemValue="#{option.value}" itemLabel="#{option.label}" />
  <p:ajax event="change" update="priorityGroup" />                 
</p:selectOneMenu>
                 
<h:panelGroup id="priorityGroup" style="padding-left: 30px;">
  <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="priority" value="#{someController.priority}"/>  
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Your snippet's code is not so much helpful.

Comment: This question is not PrimeFaces related. PF is **not** responsible for the css of an `h:selectBooleanCheckbox`. To me it looks like you have some custom css that is initially not applied or afterwards not.

Comment: I agree with you that Primefaces are not responsible for the strange behavior. I have just added as an info that Primefaces are also present in my environment. Will check for any custom css. Thank you!

Comment: By creating a [mcve]  you will most likely find the cause.

Comment: Have solved the problem. There were a css included that cause the issue. Thank you.